# drupal http_request give solr parse exception

Tags: 7, search

typing a WS uri into the navigator return the json correctly

but the same adress in $url

```
 $result=drupal_http_request( $url );
 var_dump($result->data);
```

gives a parse exception

> Cannot parse 'docid:(7000': Encountered \"\" at line 1, column
>   11.\nWas expecting one of:\n ...\n ...\n ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n ...\n \"(\" ...\n \")\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n ...\n ...\n
>   ...\n ...\n ...\n ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n ...\n \"filter(\"
>   ...\n ...\n ","code":400}

it must have smthg to do with whitespace or some special characters 
because it works with docid:(7000) but not docid:(7000 OR 7001)

How to somehow encode the url so that the solr WS server is happy with my request?

the same url works with drupal 8 code

```
   use GuzzleHttp\Client;
      $client = new Client();
      $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
```

Comment: Isn't drupal_http_request deprecated in 8?

Comment: my question is for drupal 7. I have made it work for a drupal 8 module but not the D7 one

Answer (score 0):

i found out I have had to urlencode the bracket part of my url for it to work

```
urlencode('(7000 OR 7001)'
```